Lambda node js handler not triggering other function from other file when called
I have a lambda function that has 2 files
handler & samplefile.
In my handler.js file I tried calling the function from other file but when I run the lambda it doesn't log my consoles from the sample file in my cloudwatch logs.
Node vs 16
const { sample_function } = require('./samplefile');
exports.handler = async function (event, context, callback) {
  console.log("EVENT: \n" + JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
  sample_function();
  return context.logStreamName;;
};

sample_function() {
console.log("check logs");
}

I'm expecting to run the function called from sample file when lambda function is triggered thru my handler.

So what does it log?

It only logs the console log from the handler file

You're saying that it logs your "EVENT: ..." text and then you see the standard "END RequestId ..." and "REPORT RequestId  ..." end of the Lambda function invocation logs with no other intermediate logs? If so then I would think you are not actually running the code you've shown us. Probably worth checking and then add your logs to your post.
